# How do I run SQL code using c# 3.5?

Tags: c#

I have an HTML textbox that contains some SQL code that I need executed. I am able to retrieve the actual code from the textbox but I am not sure how to go about executing the code. Any simple and elegant ways using c# 3.5?

Comment: Dear God, no, don't let users enter sql directly into a textbox!

Comment: To clarify: it's not just the security concern, though that is a BIG DEAL.  It's just too easy for even well-intentioned users to put in a query that performs poorly, hoses your server, and effectively creates a denial of service on your database.

Comment: Don't want to beat a dead horse, but it is really important that you understand that this is a terrible idea.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**DON'T EXECUTE CODE FROM A TEXTBOX**

unless you really trust what is being entered.

If you do, use this:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Your connection string");
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(TexdtBox1.Text, con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close()
```

Note that this will not return anything, jsut run the query.   If you want to return data, you need a SqlDataAdaptor or SqlDataReader.

Comment: on 'trusing' the input:  it's not just the security.  it's the performance.  It's very easy for even a well-intentioned to user to accidentally create what amounts to a denial of service attack on your database with ad hoc sql.

Comment: Executing SQL code from a textbox is a pretty scary thought however the application is going to be used by those who already have access to the DB. The app just makes their lives easier by auto generating the scripts and allows them to execute it without SQL Management Studio. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 12):

[image]

Comment: +1 only a matter of time ... I remember when that came out, laughed quite hard :-)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of database you want to execute it against. If I can assume you want to talk to a SQL Server database, look at the following classes:

- [SqlConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx) class
- [SqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx) class

Comment: Yes, I posted the answer and edited it, both to fix that and add the links.

Answer (score 0):

Create a [SqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx) with the CommandText from your textbox.

Answer (score 0):

here's a little (untested untested because typed right in the SO textbox) sample code:

```
using System.Data;

namespace MyGreatNamespace
{
    class MyGreatClass
    {
        static public DataTable executeTable( string query )
        {
            return executeTable( query, null, null );
        }

        static public DataTable executeTable( string query, string[] params, object[] values )
        {
                    DataTable myTable = new DataTable();
            using ( SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection( myConnectionString ) )
            using( SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand( connection ) )
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                command.CommandText = myQuery;

                if ( parameters.Count == values.Count && parameters.Count > 0 )
                {
                    for( int i = 0; i < parameters.Count; i ++ )
                    {
                        command.addParameterWithValue( parameters[i], values[i] );
                    }
                }

                using( SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter( command ) )
                {
                    adapter.Fill( out myTable );
                }
            }
            return myTable;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend it, but if you do, at least validate that the SQL entered starts with SELECT and does not contain any semi-colons (;) or comment characters (-- and /*).