# How can I get a username and password from my database in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, t-sql, sql-injection

I have the following code in my `btn_click` event:

```
Sqlconnection con = new Sqlconnection("server=.;database=bss;user id=ab;pwd=ab");
con.open();
SqlCommand cmd = new Sqlcommand("select * from login where username='" 
+ txt4name.Text + "' and pwd='" + txt4pwd.Text + "'", con);

SqlDataReader reader = cmd.execute Reader();
```

Where `login` is the table and `username` and `pwd` are its fields. After this code all the values are stored in the `reader` object. I want to store `username` and `pwd` in the separate variables.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Could you plz give your question a little more descriptive name

Comment: Could you please write “please” instead of “plz”?

Comment: @Jonik: Please don't be so quick to criticize the guy. English is probably not his first language. We usually like to edit these questions and help the people out.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In general, when accessing your DB, you should be using something similar to this instead to eliminate SQL injection vulnerabilities:

```
using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME=@username AND PASSWORD=HASHBYTES('SHA1', @password)", myConnection))
    {                    
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", user);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", pass);

        myConnection.Open();
        SqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
        ...................
    }
```

**But more realistically to store credentials, you should be using something like the [Membership system](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx) instead of rolling your own.**

Comment: The only problem with this is that if he were to go and use this code it would likely not return anything because I have a feeling he is not using any sort of encryption on his passwords. What you are suggesting is definitely best practices, but it might help to add in explanation on the passwords.

Comment: @TheTXI: That is fine, I don't want him to use that code. I want him to use the membership providers.

Comment: +1 for mentioning using an SHA1 hash.  If you do roll your own, you really should be using hashes instead of storing plaintext passwords in the database.

Answer (score 7):

[You're running a huge risk of sql injection with that.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)  Use SQL Parameters for values into SqlCommands.

Comment: Rich and buyutec beat me to it :)

Answer (score 4):

If you mean c# variables, and if you want to get them from db, just do this:

```
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.execute Reader();
if (reader.Read())
{
    string username = reader["username"];
    string pwd = reader["password"];
}
```

While you are at it, parameterize your query and prevent sql injection:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new Sqlcommand("select * from login where username=@username and pwd=@pwd", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txt4name.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwd", txt4pwd.Text);
```

Comment: You really should not be advocating this kind of credential storage.

Comment: Not advocating, just telling. We do not know if this will go into real time code or is asked just for learning purposes.

Comment: @buyutec: It is still your responsibility to inform and educate him.

Comment: I do not think I have a responsibility (: Also I cannot know if the asker is aware of the ideal situation but ignoring it just for making the question clearer or she has no clue. This is supposed to be a Q&A site. If you want to learn best practices, you can simply ask for them.

Comment: @buyutec: Well then you deserve my downvote. I would feel ashamed of myself if I had your outlook.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely heed the advice about SQL injection but here is the answer to your question:

```
String username;
String pwd;

int columnIndex = reader.GetOrdinal("username");

if (!dataReader.IsDBNull(columnIndex))
{
    username = dataReader.GetString(columnIndex);
}

columnIndex = reader.GetOrdinal("pwd");

if (!dataReader.IsDBNull(columnIndex))
{
    pwd = dataReader.GetString(columnIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string userName =  txt4name.Text;
string password =  txt4pwd.Text;
```

Is that really what you want? Just to get that data into variables?

Answer (score 0):

You really need to use parameterized SQL. [There's an example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546199/how-do-i-run-sql-code-using-c-3-5/546259) 
Furthermore, your question doesn't really make sense; you want the username and password in seperate variables? they already are seperate in your example. If you are unable to assign them to strings I suggest following some [tutorials](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en-us&q=c%23+tutorial&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8).

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to load the reader results into a DataTable like so:

```
DataTable Result = new DataTable();

Result.Load(reader);
```

If your login table only contains two columns (userName and password) that are unique you end up with Result containing only one row with the information.  You can then get the column values from each column:

```
string userName = Result.Rows[0].Field<string>("userName");
string password = Result.Rows[0].Field<string>("pwd");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void but_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string cn = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=mvrdatabase;Integrated Security=True";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cn);
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select count (*) from logintable where username ='" + txt_uname.Text + "'and password='" + txt_pass.Text + "'", con);
    int i = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
    con.Close();

    if (i == 1)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        MessageBox.Show("User login successfully........");
        this.Hide();
        f2.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("INCORRECT USERID AND PASSWORD", "Error");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can usually find basic usage examples on MSDN, like [this one for SqlDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx).

Comment: GIYF type of answers are really not welcome here. Either help him, or just leave it alone.

Comment: @Rich B, how is providing a link to resource containing the answer is not helping? Oh, i see, you've got a nice upvote/downvote ratio there. Good luck in your personal crusade.

Comment: @Constantin: Just providing a link is looked down upon here. Explain your answer. Do the work.