# Simple Login using C# in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I just started programing in ASP.NET and I'm currently making a simple Login page. I already have a database for the users and their password so what I want to do is when a user enter a username and password I want the program to check if theres a matching records in the database and allow the user to login (like any login page would do). I know the logic but I really need a head start in this.

I just dont like the built in Login control nor applying a Custom Membership Profile. Took me a month figuring those and I still couldnt get it and my boss doesn't like it either.

Any help would be much appreciated ;)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't like the circular wheels that cars have, I don't understand how they work, and so I'm inventing triangular ones. Also my boss doesn't like the circular ones so I must be doing the right thing!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/565425/how-can-i-get-a-username-and-password-from-my-database-in-c

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A basic idea

```
protected void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SYSTEM1;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    string sql;
    sql = "select *from user1 where uname ='" + TextBox1.Text + "' and pwd = '" + TextBox2.Text + "'";
    cmd.CommandText = sql;
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr.Read())
    {
        Response.Redirect("User.aspx");
    }
}
```

This is just an idea you can implement in more secure way

Comment: It is a very bad practice to concatenate variables directly within a sql statement

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim connection As OleDbConnection
Dim connStr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnStr").ConnectionString

Try
    connection = New OleDbConnection(connStr)
    connection.Open()

    If connection.State = Data.ConnectionState.Open Then
        Dim query As String = "Select * from Members where email='" + txtUser.Text + "' And password='" + txtPass.Text + "'"
        Dim sqlcom As New OleDbCommand(query, connection)
        Dim myreader As OleDbDataReader = sqlcom.ExecuteReader()
        myreader.Read()
        If myreader.HasRows = True Then
              User found do something
        Else
            User not found
        End If
        myreader.Close()
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
Finally
    connection.Close()
End Try
```

Comment: Unless you at least use parameters, this is how not to do it. See wikipedia for SQL Injection.

Comment: Also, this is VB.NET and the TS is asking for C#

Answer (score 0):

I would take a fresh look at building a Custom Membership Provider, you dont need to implement all the methods, just the ones you need to login and you can build it up from there. You will find a few examples on the web on how to do this.

Comment: Aye. Will do this for the meantime. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is probably to use a customer membership provider - you can keep it very simple.

But as you've indicated you don't want to do this, you could just make use of Forms Authentication (which will take care of storing the logged in user ID in a cookie) and take care of writing the user details to the database yourself. Remember to hash the password before storing.

Answer (score 0):

After Validating the User you need set the Authentication Cookie and Redirect from Login Url.Look in to FormAuthentication and Authentication and authorization settings in Web.Config.